# how to discover which .cache.html going to be loaded by chrome or firefox

Tags: gwt

**GWT module** compiled with **6 permutations** and it generates `6 .cache.html files`. How to identify which `.cache.html file` will be loaded if the modules are accessed from **firefox** or **chrome** ?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? or manually, looking at the generated files?

Comment: i want to do it programmatically. using ant script i have to read all gwt files and extract firefox and chrome specific files. Output style is OBF[USCATED]

Comment: Sounds like you'd better use `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8,safari"/>` to only compile those 2 permutations. But otherwise see Manolo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

- If you are using latest GWT-2.5, you have a file in the output folder called `compilation-mappings.txt` which contains the file name of each permutation and the value of the properties for each one (user.agent, locale, etc).

  *Note*:  The `compilation-mappings.txt` only is produced if you enable the `CrossSiteIframeLinker` in your `.gwt.xml` file :

  <add-linker name="xsiframe">
- For older gwt versions you can

  - inspect the network traffic with firebug (or any inspector like that) just in the moment the permutation is requested
  - in client side have a method which prints out the permutation name GWT.getPermutationStrongName()
  - in server side you can read the X-GWT-Permutation header sent by the client in each ajax request.

Comment: In gwt-2.5.0 final, I don't find a compilation-mappings.txt anywhere.  However, if you enable -extra and look in the extras/<module>/symbolMaps directory, the symbolMap files are named by strong permutation name and the first three lines of each symbolMap file contains the permutation number and the user.agent and locale combinations.

Comment: Actually it only produces the `compilation-mappings.txt` just in the case you use the `CrossSiteIframeLinker`. Edited my answer to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your page, open the *Inspector* (right-click), then go to *Network* tab, and then refresh. You should see all the ressources loaded.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: is it possible programmatically? . using ant script after GWT compiles